# Easier way to draw this?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to draw a type of crosshair with the Java graphics methods. I wrote this but it seems way overkill and I feel like it can be simplified quite a bit. I will include a picture of what it looks like.

How can I simplify this?

```
    graphics.setColor(mainColor);
    graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x - 13, Mouse.getPos().y - 13, 27, 27); // Rectangle stroke.
    graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x, Mouse.getPos().y - 512, 1, 500);     // Top y axis stroke.
    graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x, Mouse.getPos().y + 13, 1, 500);      // Bottom y axis stroke.
    graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x + 13, Mouse.getPos().y, 800, 1);      // Right x axis stroke.
    graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x - 812, Mouse.getPos().y, 800, 1);     // left x axis stroke.
    graphics.fillOval(Mouse.getPos().x - 3, Mouse.getPos().y - 3, 7, 7);     // Center dot stroke.
    graphics.setColor(offColor);
    graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x - 12, Mouse.getPos().y - 12, 25, 25); // Rectangle.
    graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x, Mouse.getPos().y - 512, 0, 500);     // Top y axis line.
    graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x, Mouse.getPos().y + 13, 0, 500);      // Bottom y axis line.
    graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x + 13, Mouse.getPos().y, 800, 0);      // Right x axis line.
    graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x - 812, Mouse.getPos().y, 800, 0);     // left x axis line.
    graphics.fillOval(Mouse.getPos().x - 2, Mouse.getPos().y - 2, 5, 5);     // Center dot.
```

This is what it looks like and what it's supposed to look like.
[image]

Comment: Why don't you just make a PNG image and draw it where you want it?

Comment: For a start, you could assign Mouse.getPos().x to a variable x, and Mouse.getPos().y to a variable y. That would make the code shorter and more readable.

Comment: is there any specific reason why you use `drawRect` instead of `drawLine`?

Comment: `drawLine` ought to be more efficient than `drawRect`. Using variables and a loop instead of repeating near-identical code lines would make the code more concise, readable, easily modifiable and maintainable, but wouldn't make it more efficient. Note that if you have working code that you'd like to improve it's more appropriate for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simplification would be to make a method that wraps the `Graphics#drawRect` method.

**Example**:

```
private static void drawRect (Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    g.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x + x, Mouse.getPos().y + y, width, height);
}
```

**Then this calling code goes from**:

```
graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x - 13, Mouse.getPos().y - 13, 27, 27); // Rectangle stroke.
graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x, Mouse.getPos().y - 512, 1, 500);     // Top y axis stroke.
graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x, Mouse.getPos().y + 13, 1, 500);      // Bottom y axis stroke.
graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x + 13, Mouse.getPos().y, 800, 1);      // Right x axis stroke.
graphics.drawRect(Mouse.getPos().x - 812, Mouse.getPos().y, 800, 1);     // left x axis stroke.
```

**To**:

```
drawRect(graphics, -13, -13, 27, 27);  // Rectangle stroke.
drawRect(graphics, 0, -512, 1, 500);   // Top y axis stroke.
drawRect(graphics, 0, 13, 1, 500);     // Bottom y axis stroke.
drawRect(graphics, 13, 0, 800, 1);     // Right x axis stroke.
drawRect(graphics, -812, 0, 800, 1);   // left x axis stroke.
```